# Does django-ckeditor works with django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-ckeditor, django-modeltranslation

I use django-modeltranslation to translate some text fields into several languagues. This works well. Now I want to implement django-ckeditor and this is working for not translated field as well. Problem is with fields which is translated (this fields are registered in translation.py).

Does anybody using these two apps together? Is there something to do to get translated text fields working with ckeditor?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I found, that this combination works well without any extra settings. Problem was between chair and screen (bad model was selected).